# Invalidating cached content with google cloud sdk python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cdn

It's possible to invalidating cached content with Google Cloud Python SDK?

I use `google.cloud.storage` to upload file in the bucket.

However, I haven't found a Python library for CDN.

There is only `glcoud` tools ...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `urlMaps.invalidateCache` API method provided with the `google-api-python-client` package, see https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/urlMaps/invalidateCache for more details and a Python example.